# Are collections required?

Tags: backbone.js

Sorry this is a noob question but if I only need some initial data when the application first loads is a collection always needed or can the model fetch the data and pass it directly to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in backbone is really "required". It's a very thin, more-than-one-way-to-do-it framework. Jeremy recommends data that can be bootstrapped in the initial page load be handled that way, so your HTML could include you initial data as JSON in a `<script>` tag. You can pass that JSON to a Backbone.Collection (if it's a list of similar records) or a new Backbone.Model (if it's a single domain object). You can also just use a model and call `model.fetch` to get your initial data. Model vs. Collection is more about single domain object with name/value pairs vs list of many objects where iterating, sorting, filtering are common.

Comment: Thanks Peter, thats what I thought but every tutorial I've seen uses collections and because of that I was confused. Your explanation was exactly what I needed to move on with confidence.